# how to move this section in a grey area after add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9

how can i move this section in a grey box after add to cart area 
[image]

this is a product view page i am trying it n catalog.xml but it is not working

```
<reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" after="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

[image]